# Linux file copy with ETA?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, copying, cp

I'm copying a large amount of files between disks.  There's approximately 16 GB of data.
I'd like to see progress information, and even an estimated time of completion **from the command line**.

Any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `rsync --human-readable --progress`.

For single files and block devices there's also `pv`.  And if you genuinely need an accurate progress bar, try using `tar` with pv — something like this:

```
source=/the/source/directory
target=/the/target/directory
size=$(du -sx "$source")
cd "$source"
find . xdev -depth -not -path ./lost+found -print0 \
    | tar --create --atime-preserve=system --null --files-from=- \
          --format=posix --no-recursion --sparse \
    | pv --size ${size}k \
    | { cd "$target"; \
        tar --extract --overwrite --preserve-permissions --sparse; }
```

Be warned, however, that GNU `tar` does not yet support ACLs or extended attributes, so if you are copying filesystems mounted with the "acl" or "xattrs" options, you need to use rsync (with the "`--acls`" and "`--xattrs`" options).  Personally, I use:

```
rsync --archive --inplace --hard-links --acls --xattrs --devices --specials \
    --one-file-system --8-bit-output --human-readable --progress /source /target
```

Also look into whether you want to use the `--delete` and/or `--numeric-ids` options.

Comment: Was posting that. However, be aware that it doesn't provide a reliable "progress over total copy time".

However, rsync brings many benefits to this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `dd` I would suggest [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml), e.g.:

```
% tar -cf - INPUT | pv -rbe -s SIZE | tar -xf - -C DEST
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `rsync -P`? If you're using `dd`, e.g. `tar -cf - src | dd | (cd dest; tar -xf -)` you should be able to use Ctrl-T (SIGINFO) to see your progress.

Comment: Linux doesn't even have `SIGINFO`.

Comment: When copying with `dd` I send SIGUSR1 to `dd` instead to cause it to print the statistics. A simple `killall -USR1 dd` will do the job. (Which works on Linux, even if, as Teddy points out, Ctrl+T doesn’t work.)